# Offscreen rendering of my own Shader with Apple's Metal sample doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, metal

Apple sample program

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/customizing_render_pass_setup

I'm thinking of making Swift and using my own Shader for offscreen rendering.
Swift conversion itself was done without problems.
When I wrote the following monochromatic Shader there, I was able to output it to the screen without any problems.

```
fragment float4 simpleFragmentShader(VertexOut vertexIn [[stage_in]] {
    return float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

However, if you use the following Shade, the screen will turn black immediately and you will not be able to output properly.
This Shader works fine with normal Metal code, but it just didn't work in the sample environment above.
When using such a Shader in the above sample code, is it possible to use it without changing the sample code or somewhere in the Shader?

```
vertex VertexOut simpleVertexShader(constant float4 *positions [[buffer(0)]],
 uint vid [[ vertex_id ]]) {
    
    VertexOut out;
    
    out.pos = positions[vid];
    
    return out;
}


fragment float4 simpleFragmentShader(VertexOut vertexIn [[stage_in]],
                                     constant float2 &resolution [[buffer(0)]]) {

    float2 resolution0 = float2(resolution[0], resolution[1]);
    float2 p = (vertexIn.pos.xy * 2.0 - resolution0) / min(resolution0.x, resolution0.y);

    return float4(p, 0.0, 1.0);
    
}
```

[image]

The image is for success.

There is no problem with basic descriptions such as resolution.

```
renderEncoder.setFragmentBuffer(resolutionBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
```

Addition of Shader of the final rendering.

```
vertex VertexTextureOut textureVertexShader(constant float4 *positions [[buffer(0)]],
                                            constant float2 *texcoord [[buffer(1)]],
                                            uint vid [[ vertex_id ]]) {
    
    VertexTextureOut out;
    
    out.pos = positions[vid];
    out.texcoord = texcoord[vid];
    
    return out;
}

fragment float4 textureFragmentShader(VertexTextureOut vertexIn [[stage_in]],
                                     texture2d<float> renderTargetTexture [[texture(0)]]) {
    
    constexpr sampler simpleSampler;

    // Sample data from the texture.
    float4 colorSample = renderTargetTexture.sample(simpleSampler, vertexIn.texcoord);

    // Return the color sample as the final color.
    return colorSample;
}
```

Comment: Please attach more code, it's unclear what you are asking and what's happening.

Comment: The code of the main body is still a sample. I changed only the simpleFragmentShader side that is saved as the texture of it.
Is the pie line side the problem as a code? Or do you see the problem on the renderer side? As mentioned above, if it is a monochromatic Shader, no problem has occurred. So, I thought that the shader side was also a problem, but ...

Comment: What are you setting 'resolution' x and y values to?

Comment: ```let screenSize = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size```

The width and hight of the entire screen you want to render are set to the x and y values ​​of resolution. I ported that part to what is output without problems in normal rendering.

Comment: Added Shader for final rendering above.
I was wondering if I could just paste the texture, but is there a problem with this part?

Comment: The resolution is as follows.
```let screenSize = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size
resolutionX = Float(screenSize.width), resolutionY = Float(screenSize.height)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that 'in.texcoord.xy' is already using normalized coordinates so they are already in the range on 0.0-1.0

This works:

```
float2 p = (in.texcoord.xy) ;
return float4(p, 0.0, 1.0);
```

**Update:** using your sample project and:

```
float2 p = (vertexIn.pos.xy) / min(resolution0.x, resolution0.y);
return float4(p, 0.0, 1.0);
```

I get these results which seems correct:

[image]

**Update 2:**
The sample project 2 crashes for me. I had to comment out these two lines (line 63 and 65 of Renderer.swift:

```
//textureDescriptor.textureType = .type2DMultisample
//textureDescriptor.sampleCount = 4
```

That got me to a partially black screen. Next I changed line 29 of Shaders.metal to:

```
float2 p = (vertexIn.pos.xy) / min(resolution0.x, resolution0.y);
```

Which gave me expected results:

[image]

Comment: It may seem strange at first glance, but as you can see in the image, this Shader works if it's not offScreenRendaring. Even if you use GLSL with OpenGL (webGL), it works as follows in this way of writing.

Comment: In the case of such a Shader, does it mean that there is no data as color even if it is output by offScreenRendaring?

Comment: OK so I guess you want the color to be based on the coordinates. Make sure your math for P works out so that the X and Y values are in the range of 0 to 1.

Comment: I think it probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: I tried it, but the result did not change and the screen remained black. I think it's not a problem when trying to normalize on Shader and do something, but a problem with offScreenRendaring. Something like Shader above doesn't work with offScreenRendaring, is it a problem when outputting as Texture, or is it a problem when pasting and rendering it? When the whole screen was a single color, it was output without any problem, and when pasting a normal texture, there seemed to be no problem.

Comment: It definitely works here, so you must be doing something else wrong in addition. What happens if you return `float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`? It should be all red.

Comment: It turns red without any problems.
Since situations other than Shader are possible, add the code related to offScreenRendering to the question content.

Comment: That means you are incorrectly calculating p. Should not be very difficult for you to figure out why it is not in the range of 0 to 1.

Comment: Make a sample project with your code and I can take a look, otherwise, I've done about all I can to help.

Comment: I got an answer
```float2 p = (in.texcoord.xy);
return float4 (p, 0.0, 1.0);```
But there is a problem, and it becomes a mystery that Metal that is not offScreenRenddaring like the captured image of iPhone X in the question can handle it.How should it fit in the microwave?

Comment: I have prepared a sample below.
https://sgaworks.com/metalsample/MetalSample.zip
```float2 resolution0 = float2 (resolution [0], resolution [1]);
    float2 p = (vertexIn.pos.xy * 2.0 --resolution0) / min (resolution0.x,-(resolution0.y));```
However, since green was displayed, it is presumed that it did not fit, but is it that the value given to resolution is incorrect?

Comment: Try `float2 p = (vertexIn.pos.xy) / min(resolution0.x, resolution0.y);`.  Does that do what you want?

Comment: I tried it, but it just showed a black screen.
I'm sorry many times. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know, but when I use that in your sample project it works here.

Comment: This sample works fine, but the offScreen rendering sample I'll provide later will turn black. Excuse me a moment.

Comment: Below is a sample of the problem.
https://sgaworks.com/metalsample/MetalSample2.zip

With offScreen rendering, there is a problem. For the final result, I want to output the Metal Sample mentioned earlier. However, only a part of it is rendered or only a black screen is output.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I didn't think it was wrong to make it a Texture type.
But it's not completely 0,1 yet.
Use p earlier
```float cA = smoothstep (0.5, 0.51, length (p));```
If you make a circle like this, it will become an ellipse, and it is a problem that it will not be as usual with such a rendering method.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I would advise that unless you know what you are changing to leave settings default.